# How reorder row in customize UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

So far I have customized my UITableViewCell with the icon reorder row.

[image]

I want my cell can be reordered when long press on the reorder icon and then move it.
The image below is what I have expected.

[image]

I have read many document they provided only long press on cell and move it but I don't want it because long press on cell I have my another gesture is renaming it; and also I don't want to use the edit/done of UITableView default from OS; so I decided to put reorder icon but I can not do, because I'm new in objective c.

Can anyone help by providing sample code here?

Thank for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Override two methods of UITableViewDataSource

For reordering to work you will first need to bring the Table in editing mode. Which you can either do it from viewDidLoad or from a IBAction method.

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     self.myTableView.editing = YES;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  return YES;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath{
   //Manipulate your data array.
}
```

By Default editing style is UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete. So if you don't override the below method it will show both rearrange as well delete icon.

```
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

Since, you have long gesture of your cell causes issue with the long gesture of the re-ordering of cell. You can add a UIView to the cell. Add all your elements in this UIView. Now, attach a UILongPress Gesture to this  UIView (not to the cell.).

Comment: Actually when I click on cell it will navigate to another view to display detail information. so I can not put self.myTableView.editing = YES; if i put it -> my cell doesn't work.

What I want is just long press on my reorder icon to reorder row because my icon is from my UITableViewCell customized.
Can you help me? Thank

Comment: it shows wide space on left side. can it be possible to remove this space??